# Can I import or upload an audio file to soundcloud via the api using a URL vs. file data?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to upload/import a track to soundcloud via their api.

Right now, it looks like you can only upload an audio file, but you can only do it by POSTing the file data.

My question is, is it possible to import to soundcloud (through the api) from a URL?

sort of like they do here: http://importer.soundcloudlabs.com

but via the soundcloud api.

Any ideas?  I don't really want to make this a 2 legged process (download audio file, then upload file data to soundcloud)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. On the importer, you'll probably find that behind the scenes, it's doing that two-step itself. User inputs url, back end server downloads file, then uploads to SoundCloud API.

Comment: yeah, I think you are right... I just ended up doing the 2 legged process... slight lag but not too bad w/ shorter files.